# Passing json data from python to rust via pickle (or other)

Tags: python, rust, python-cffi

I'm trying to create a generic interface to be able to use rust libraries from python(https://github.com/ProjitB/Rust-Libraries-to-Python). Right now while I have a working version, I am creating a temporary file in the process of passing data, which I want to avoid. Any ideas on how to do this?

So what I do is that I write an interface function in rust, which invoked the rust library functions I want to use from python. To pass arguments from python, I am writing it to a tempfile via pickle, and the read the args on the rust side through serde_pickle.

What I'm stuck at is that while I am able to pass strings from python to rust(ex, the filename itself is being passed right now as a string), when I am not able to do so with pickle serialized data. Perhaps it is to due to null bytes?

```py
# Rust Function Interface Definitions
ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef("""
   typedef struct {int length; const char* response;} RetStruct;
   RetStruct rust_post(const char*);

""") 
LIB = ffi.dlopen("target/release/librequest_export.dylib")

def function_call(function, data):
    inp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    with open(inp_file.name, 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(data, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    val = function(to_string(inp_file.name))
    obj = pickle.loads(read_pickle_bytes(val.response, val.length))
    return obj['response']

def test_function_call():
    data = {'url': 'https://postman-echo.com/post', 'data': {"hello": "world"}}
    output = eval(function_call(LIB.rust_post, data))
    print(type(output))
    print(output)
    print(output["args"])

test_function_call()
```

```rust
use reqwest;
use url::Url;
use std::os::raw::c_char;
use std::ffi::CStr;
use serde_json as json;
use serde_pickle as pickle;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Read};
use std::mem;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct RetStruct {
    length: i64,
    response: *mut u8
}

pub extern "C" fn rust_post(input_temp_file: *const c_char) -> RetStruct{
    // File to read and write to
    let input_filename = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(input_temp_file).to_str().expect("Not a valid UTF-8 string") };

    //Processing
    let reader: Box<Read> = Box::new(File::open(input_filename).unwrap());
    let decoded: json::Value = pickle::from_reader(reader).unwrap();
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();

    //To Implement
    let data = &decoded["data"];
    let url = Url::parse(&decoded["url"].as_str().expect("Not a valid UTF-8 string")).unwrap();
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let mut resp = client.post(url)
        .json(&data)
        .send().unwrap();
    map.insert("response".to_string(), resp.text().unwrap());

    //Processing
    let mut serialized = serde_pickle::to_vec(&map, true).unwrap();
    let x = serialized.len();
    let p = serialized.as_mut_ptr();
    mem::forget(serialized);
    RetStruct{
    length: x as i64,
    response: p
    }
}
```

The code shows how I'm currently passing data between python and rust. If I try to send the serialized pickle data in the manner that I send the filename, I am not able to recover all of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to serialize to json.

```
print({'url': 'https://postman-echo.com/post', 'data': {"hello": "world"}})
```

is `{'url': 'https://postman-echo.com/post', 'data': {'hello': 'world'}}`

```
import json

print(json.dumps({'url': 'https://postman-echo.com/post', 'data': {"hello": "world"}}))
```

is `{"url": "https://postman-echo.com/post", "data": {"hello": "world"}}`

Quotes matter, notice `'` and `"` difference.

Comment: to clarify, my exact issue is when I do a pickle.dumps(json_data), and then try to pass that as a parameter to my rust interface from the python side, I am not able to deserialize it on the rust side.

Comment: JSON with single quotes are invalid, so json parse should fail (on the rust side). You are not pickling a json but a pyhton dict.

Comment: If I write it to a file, and read it from the rust side, it works perfectly. However I am facing issues with the same process when I try to send it as a string instead of using the temporary file.